# Mysql DATETIME related queries: how to calculate the expired entry?

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

i have a table that has a cell containing a timestamp when the entry was created,
than i have a cell containing the number of days that row should expire, something like this `my_tb`:

```
id  |  elem1   |   timestamp    |  maxdays   |  active
1   |  jondoe  |   2010-09-28   |    60      |     1
1   |  foo     |   2010-09-18   |    30      |     1
1   |  janedo  |   2010-09-08   |   120      |     1
1   |  bar     |   2010-08-28   |    30      |     0
```

maxdays is the value in days (60 = 2 months etc..)

i basically need a query to calculate when those entries expires

i though something like this but i dont know how to translate it in a real query (this below doesnt work)

```
SELECT * FROM my_tb WHERE timestamp+maxdays < NOW()
```

so basically with this query i can check if a row has exceeded the number of days (starting thetimestamp date) and then i can update the cell `active` to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM my_tb WHERE timestamp + INTERVAL maxdays DAY < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is an amount of of seconds.

One day equals 24 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds) so your query should looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tb WHERE timestamp + ( maxdays * 24 * 60 * 60 ) < NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
SELECT * FROM password_change_requests WHERE username=:username AND time + 3600 > NOW()
```

to find an entry that is less than an hour old. The SELECT statement is a PDO statement by the way, if you're wondering why it looks a little funny.